# Multiple variables in derivative and finding the slope

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

I'm working on slope and geometrical differentiation. The problem is to find the slope of any point on the curve $$\frac{x^2}{3^2} + \frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1$$

I have found its derivative: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-4}{9} \frac{x}{y}$. The next requirement is to give the numerical value of the slope at x = 1. I obviously should give x the value of 1 in the derivative to calculate but how should I approach dealing with the value of y? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are finding the slope at various points, what value does $y$ have in the original equation when $x=1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

If $x = 1$, then:

$$\frac{1^{2}}{3^{2}} + \frac{y^{2}}{2^{2}} = 1$$

Can you use this to solve for all values of the $y$ coordinate?

Comment: Or for **all** values of the $y$ coordinate?

Comment: @User58220, thanks. Edited for clarity.